# wordpress $wpdb->get_results() function and strange result from Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am using get_results function on 'user' table in wordpress with matching displayname and its giving me perfect result as following.

my query : `$query_result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users WHERE display_name = '".$datavalue."'", ARRAY_N);`

and the result i get is an array `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => zubair [2] => hidden user pass [3] => zubair [4] => zubair@modec.ae [5] => [6] => 2015-12-26 19:23:49 [7] => hidden activation key [8] => 0 [9] => Zubair Khan ) )`

this array is saved in a variable name $result;
now i'm trying to echo results as following and getting strange results.

```
echo $result[0][0];

echo $result[0][3];
echo $result[0][9];
```

first echo statement prints '222' ,second echo statement prints 'zubairzubair' and last echo statement prints 'Zubair KhanZubair Khan'

any suggestion, what i'm missing or doing wrong?

here is my complete code:

```
function list_input_check($datakey, $datavalue){
global $wpdb;
$result = -1;


if($datakey = "username"){

    $query_result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users WHERE display_name = '".$datavalue."'", ARRAY_N);
    if(count($query_result)>0){

        $result = $query_result[0][9];
        echo "result to return is : ".$result;
    }
    else{
        $result = -1;
    }

}
if($datakey = "branchname"){
    $query_result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->branches WHERE branch_name = '".$datavalue."'", ARRAY_N);


    if(count($query_result)>0){
        //$result = true;
    }
}
return $result;}
```

Comment: Please post your code that makes the query and output.

Comment: I have updated post and added my function which is querying database

Comment: there is nothing in the function to do what you have described, check how you are using the function